# How do I work out how much data a stored procedure returns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I work out how much data (in KB) a stored procedure returns? I can't see a column in profiler that might indicate this, other than Binary Data.

Can I do it with a SQL Server tool like profiler, or should I use something like Wireshark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio with "Include Client Statistics" selected.
The Client Statistics tab in the results pane will include a figure for "Bytes received from server."

Answer (score 3):

Right click th empty space in SSMS.and select the `Include Client Statistics`

[image]
Bytes received from server – is the amount of data the SQL Server has sent to the client, measured in bytes

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to write query to "Include Clients Statistics" instead of right click and select?